# copy/paste/move files in kdevelop

Tags: kde, ide

I can create/delete files but I cant copy/paste/move files in any view(filesystem or project). kdevelop version is **4.3.1**.

Is it possible to enable this obvious feauture?

Comment: yeah very disappointing for an IDE...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In KDevelop 4.5 this feature has been added:
http://nikosams.blogspot.co.at/2012/10/kdevelop-project-and-filesystem-view.html

There is no stable release though....